# Add a date to the tab

Tags: excel, vba

The macro/coding below creates pivot tables in a new worksheet, the tab gets named based off the what it's filter on.  For example I have 3 brands, it will create a tab for the 3 brands and name the tab based off the brand (Brand 1, Brand 2 & Brand 3).  I'm trying to update the coding so it includes a date in the name by having it referencing it from a specific cell in the worksheet since I will have to update the date every month.  So if I have 6.15.20 in cell A1 I would like to tell the macro to reference A1 (which would have the date) to name the tab "Brand 1 6.15.20", right now it only names the tab Brand 1.  Is there a way to do that?

**Assuming it needs to be updated around this area of the code**

For Each pi In pf.PivotItems

strPI = Replace(Left(pi.Name, 31), "/", " ")      <- this is where i probably need to update?

Below is my entire coding.

Appreciate any help!

```
On Error GoTo errHandler
Application.DisplayAlerts = False

Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim pt As PivotTable
Dim pf As PivotField
Dim pi As PivotItem
Dim strPF As String
Dim strPI As String

Set ws = Sheets("Invoice PVTTBL Template")
Set pt = ws.PivotTables(1)
Set pf = pt.PageFields(1)
strPF = pf.Name

For Each pi In pf.PivotItems
  strPI = Replace(Left(pi.Name, 31), "/", " ")
  On Error Resume Next
    Sheets(strPI).Delete
  On Error GoTo 0
  ws.Copy After:=Sheets(Sheets.Count)
  With ActiveSheet
    .Name = strPI
    With .PivotTables(1).PivotFields(strPF)
      .PivotItems(pi.Name).Visible = True
      .CurrentPage = pi.Name
    End With
  End With

Next pi

ws.Activate

MsgBox "Invoices Created"

exitHandler:
  Application.DisplayAlerts = True
  Exit Sub
errHandler:
  MsgBox "Could not create sheets"
  Resume exitHandler

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out: 
Hope this helps someone in the future in order to reference a cell to an already existing formula I used the below.  This is based off my formula above.

strPI = Replace(Left(pi.Name & " " & ws.Range("O1"), 31), "/", " ")

so now in stead of the name on the tab being "Brand 1" it will show a date due to me referencing a cell that has the date i need.  The new name on the tab looks like this "Brand 1 6.15.20"